# Sequence spaces are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\ell^{\infty}=\left\{(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{C}\mid \sup_n\|x_n\|<\infty\right\}$ the space of bounded sequences.

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}, m>1$, be fixed. Why is the quotient space $\ell^{\infty}/\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^m\mathbb{C}$ isomorphic to $\ell^{\infty}$?

I think, if there exists an isomorphism, then this isomorphism is induced by the identity $\ell^{\infty}\to \ell^{\infty}$, or that the isomorphism is something canonical... but I don't really get this.

Comment: The notation $\ell^{\infty}/\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^m\mathbb{C}$ doesn't really make sense, because $\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^m\mathbb{C}$ is not a subspace of $\ell^\infty$. Of course $\ell^\infty$ contains many subspaces isomorphic to $\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^m\mathbb{C}$, but you need to specify which one you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to construst a linear map $\ell^\infty\to\ell^\infty$ with kernel $\bigoplus\limits_{k=1}^m\Bbb{C},$ then the isomorphism got. An intuitive idea is to throw out the first $m$ components, which is a linear map. (Mind it's not the identity map.)